# how can i find the modified files in ubuntu

Tags: unix, ubuntu, cron

I want to find the details of the modified files such as size, permission and modified time in ubuntu and set the cron jobs in cpanel,i have used like this

```
find /home1/sitename/public_html/ -type f -ctime -1 -exec ls -ls {}
```

and also like this

```
find /home1/sitename/public_html/-type f -ctime -1 -exec ls -ls {} \;
```

but it is not working .

Now I want all the details of the files modified .

Comment: use `-mtime` instead of `-ctime` if you *really* want to monitor permissions as well, you could use `-ctime -1 -o -mtime -1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
find /home1/sitename/public_html/-type f -ctime -1 | xargs ls -ls
```